# Method Reference - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Tags: java, syntax-error, method-reference

I am trying to practice java 8 features. While creating the program which uses Method Reference to Static method I got syntax Error  "*Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements*"
I don't think I have done anything wrong in my code. What am I missing?

```
MethodReferenceInteface ref1 = MethodReference::sayName();
```

Full Program:
package com.jui.bhav.Practice;

```
interface MethodReferenceInteface{

    String getName();
}

public class MethodReference {
    
    public static String sayName() {
        return "Jui";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MethodReferenceInteface ref1 = MethodReference::sayName();
        ref1.getName();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Method references contain the method name without the `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
MethodReferenceInteface ref1 = MethodReference::sayName;
```